Pro components in Vaadin development mode
I'm debugging a Vaadin Flow application using Pro Components (GridPro).
I need to run the UI on my phone, to check usability on a mobile device.
The application works, minus the pro components.
Obviously, I have an active license (Vaadin subscription) and the components work if I run the application from https://localhost/
I get this error in the browser:
Internal error: no connection

Component: vaadin-grid-pro 24.3.10



I assume you are using a local IP to access your app on your phone. If so, have you tried adding it to vaadin.devmode.hostsAllowed?
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/configuration/development-mode/dev-tools
